# ORM and dynamic sql

Tags: database

I'm building a web application that includes a database and a front-end technology (among other things). I'm wondering whether ORM is acceptable alternative to stored procedures in the database. I've read that ORM can result in poor database design, but it seems many people use it. Is it possible to use with dynamic SQL generated in the browser, that passes through the ORM in the middle tier to communicate with the database? The ORM would offer security so the world can't connect directly to the database.

Comment: Are you saying that the 'front end' (which I read as the web browser) is generating the SQL (using Javascript?) and you pass that straight through to be executed by the database? If so, that sounds like a serious security problem.

Comment: No, it's still going through the middle tier (e.g. PHP) for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be wary of the quality of any database code (PL/SQL or SQL) created by someone with, as you say, "no knowledge of Oracle database".

There's nothing wrong with using the database to provide web services though. I'd suggest looking at the [Apex Listener](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex-listener/documentation/apexlistenerdevguide1-1ea-177511.pdf) and resource templates.